# Adding items to array on click Rect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays

I am iterating through an array of objects and displaying items to the page. On button click, I would like to add the clicked item to a favourites array.

When I click on the first button multiple times the item does get added to my array multiple times. When I click on the second or third button, the item gets added but it overrides the previous items that were stored in the array. Not sure what I am doing wrong in my handleFavourites function

```
import React from "react";
import Tour from "./Tour";

const Tours = ({ tours }) => {
  return (
    <section>
      <div className="title">
        <h2>our tours</h2>
        <div className="underline"></div>
      </div>
      {tours.map((tour) => {
        return <Tour tour={tour} key={tour.id} />;
      })}
    </section>
  );
};

export default Tours;
```

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

const Tour = ({ tour }) => {
  const [favourites, setFavourites] = useState([]);

  const handleFavourites = () => {
    const clickedTour = {
      tour: tour.name,
    };
    setFavourites([...favourites, clickedTour]);
  };
  console.log(favourites);

  return (
    <article className="single-tour">
      <img alt={tour.name} src={tour.image} />
      <footer>
        <div className="tour-info">
          <h4>{tour.name}</h4>
          <h4 className="tour-price">${tour.price}</h4>
        </div>
        <p>{tour.info}</p>
        <button onClick={handleFavourites}>Add to favourite</button>
      </footer>
    </article>
  );
};

export default Tour;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each instance of your `Tour` component has its own independent `favorites` array. What you're seeing in the console is the array for the specific Tour component instance containing the clicked button.

Move the state to the parent `Tours` component and pass the add handler as a prop.

```
const Tours = ({ tours }) => {
  const [favourites, setFavourites] = useState([]);

  const handleFavourites = (tour) => {
    setFavourites([...favourites,{ tour: tour.name }]);
  };

  return (
    <section>
      <div className="title">
        <h2>our tours</h2>
        <div className="underline"></div>
      </div>
      {tours.map((tour) => {
        return (
           <Tour
             tour={tour}
             key={tour.id}
             handleFavourites={() => handleFavourites(tour)}
           />;
        )
      })}
    </section>
  );
};
```